# how to fill fields of the webpage where autocomplete is off

Tags: html, autocomplete, autofill

I want to automatically fill the registration form fields on an HTML web page. The form has multiple input boxes. I  want to define the value of fields and when the web page appears the fields fill automatically. Before, I used autofill extension for it. But, the autocomplete feature of fields has been off and HTML objects don't have names or ids. Also, they have the same class. Therefore, fields don't fill automatically. How I can fill fields on the webpage automatically?
for example, two input objects and some of codes have been defined as follow:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="red" placeholder="" type="text">
```

`<input autocomplete="off" class="red" placeholder="" type="text">`

```
<div class="input-item" max-length="10" placeholder="ID" data-v-6b0449e1=""><label class="label"><i>*</i>ID:</label><input autocomplete="off" class="ltr green" max-length="10" placeholder="" type="text"><p class="errors"><ul></ul></p></div>
<div class="select-item" data-v-6b0449e1=""><label class="label"><i>*</i>Sex:</label><select><option hidden="" disabled="" value="">Select</option><option value="false">male</option><option value="true">female</option></select><p class="errors"><ul></ul></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to fill the fields when the page loads, you can use JavaScript:

**HTML**

```html
<form class="my-form">
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" />
  <input type="text" id="input3" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("input1").value = "This is the first input";
  document.getElementById("input2").value = "This is the second input";
  document.getElementById("input3").value = "This is the third input";
}
```

All this does is just, when the page loads (`window.onload`), replaces the value of each of the specified `input` fields to whatever you set it to.

Comment: I want to automatically fill the registration form fields on an HTML web page. The form has multiple input boxes. I want to define the value of fields and when the web page appears the fields fill automatically. Before, I used autofill extension for it. But, the autocomplete feature of fields has been off and HTML objects don't have names or ids. Also, they have the same class. Therefore, fields don't fill automatically. How I can fill fields on the webpage automatically? for example, two input objects have been defined as follow: `<input  autocomplete="off"  class="red"   type="text">`

Comment: The best way to add data to an `input` element is to give it an `id` and then use that `id` in the JavaScript (`document.getElementById()`) to give it's `value`. I can't think of any other way. And do this in the `window.onload = function()` function, as all code here runs as soon as the page loads, making it appear auto-filled for the user.